# How I can create a custom progress bar with a moving image while the bar is progressing in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-progressbar

I am new with this and I am trying to create a progress bar with a countdown timer, which I did with a layer-list elements, but if I want to make it more user friendly and cute, by putting an image which moves together with the progress bar?

My thought is to extend something I guess a View?! and use an animated-list or just one image?

What is the structure of building such a thing and what elements do I need?

Sorry for my novice questions and thank you